# The operator '*' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try adding a null check to the target ('!')

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

I used this code for responsiveness in my UI. So what this code basically does is calculate the size of the screen and I use the functions below to put the exact font size according to the design provided to me in Figma or Adobe XD. Using this method, I was able to create pixel-perfect UI.

After upgrading to `Flutter 2.0.3`, I am getting null safety errors. I was able to solve most of them but I am not able to solve this error.
Please advice.

`Complete Code`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData? _mediaQueryData;
  static double? screenWidth;
  static double? screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData!.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData!.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData!.orientation;
    if (orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
      defaultSize = screenHeight! * 0.024;
    } else {
      defaultSize = screenWidth! * 0.024;
    }
  }
}

double getSize(double size) {
  var defaultsSize = SizeConfig.defaultSize * size;
  return (defaultsSize / 10);
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight!;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}

// Get the proportionate width as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth!;
  // 375 is the layout width that Figma provides
  return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
}
```

`Error`

[image]

Comment: Change it to `SizeConfig.defaultSize! * size`

Comment: So you managed to fix the same issue twice, but somehow forgot how to do it for your third method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `SizeConfig.defaultSize` is nullable, you need to make sure that its value should not be null.

You can add some assertion to notify the caller that `SizeConfig` should be initialized first. Then, you can change it to `SizeConfig.defaultSize!`.

Sample...

```
double getSize(double size) {
  assert(
    SizeConfig.defaultSize != null,
    "SizeConfig should be initialized (only once) before calling getSize(...). Refer to SizeConfig.init(...).",
  );
  var defaultsSize = SizeConfig.defaultSize! * size;
  return (defaultsSize / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

You get this error because the object you're invoking `*` on can be `null`.

Example:

```dart
int? count = 1;

void main() {
  print(count * 2); // error: The operator '*' can't be unconditionally invoked ...
}
```

---

**Solutions:**

- Use a local variable:

  ```dart
  int? count = 1;

  void main() {
    var i = count;
    if (i != null) {
      print(i * 2); // Prints 2
    }
  }
  ```
- Use bang operator (`!`)

  ```dart
  int? count = 1;

  void main() {
    print(count! * 2); // Prints 2
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

- Use the bang operator:

```dart
int? count = 1;

void main() {
  // will throw an error if count is null
  print(count! * 2);
}
```

- Use the ?? operator:

```dart
int? count = 1;

void main() {
  // safe
  print((count ?? 1) * 2);
}
```

- Use an if - else statement:

```dart
int? count = 1;

void main() {
  if(count != null) {
    print(count! * 2);
  } else {
    print('count is null');
  }
}
```